# Batch: for files greater than, for files less than

Tags: windows, batch-file, 7zip

I am looking to create a batch script that will take all image files that are larger than x, compress them in one .zip.
Then take all remaining image files that are less than that same x size and compress them in one .zip

I've tried several, several different ways and can't figure it out. I've searched on here and all mighty Google lol
My latest thoughts are listing the files that are larger in a text file temporarily and then using that list for 7zip to compress them, but can't figure out how to echo/print/list them to 7zip.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a%%b)

SET FOLDER=%~dp1
REM     Sets current directory

SET LOG="log.txt"

pushd %FOLDER%
REM     Changes directory to current

for %%a in ("%cd%") do SET NAME=%%~na
REM     Gets the last directory name and sets it as a variable

SET ZIPNAME=%NAME% - Originals.zip
SET ZIPNAME2=%NAME% - Photos.zip

if exist ".smaller.txt" del /F ".smaller.txt"
if exist ".larger.txt" del /F ".larger.txt"

if exist "%ZIPNAME%" del /F "%ZIPNAME%" | echo %MYDATE%_%MYTIME%: %COMPUTERNAME% deleted %ZIPNAME%>>%LOG%
if exist "%ZIPNAME2%" del /F "%ZIPNAME2%" | echo %MYDATE%_%MYTIME%: %COMPUTERNAME% deleted %ZIPNAME2%>>%LOG%
REM     Deletes old zips if they exists

FOR /F "usebackq delims=;" %%A IN (`dir /b *.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.gif *.bmp`) DO (

    IF %%~zA LSS 1048576 (
        ECHO %%A >>.smaller.txt
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO %%A >>.larger.txt
    )

)

FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x IN (.smaller.txt) DO SET SMALLER=!SMALLER!%%x
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x IN (.larger.txt) DO SET LARGER=!LARGER!%%x

PAUSE
```

Comment: Looking at the help file for 7zip, I see it is just like Winzip in that it can take a file name that is a list of files you want to zip.  I don't see any 7zip code in your batch file so I am not sure what you tried to zip the files.

Comment: There's no 7zip code in there yet because I can't figure that part out. 
My thoughts are something like this, 
`"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a -mx9 -tzip "%ZIPNAME%" "variable or list of files here"`

Comment: So no where in the help file did you see how to use a list file to zip up all those files into one archive.

Comment: `7z a -tzip archive.zip @listfile.txt`

Comment: @Squashman oh my gosh.. I somehow missed that @listfile.txt in all my searching! That works!
What's the most efficient way to do it, to put it in my `IF %%~zA LSS 1048576` loop and maybe change the `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a -mx9 -tzip "%ZIPNAME2%" "@.smaller.txt"` to the "a" in 7zip to "u" for update?
If I left it as "a", wouldn't it keep recreating the .zip for each file found in the loop?

Comment: Nope.  You are still not understanding how that works.  The `@` is a list of files.  You need to create the list first so you wouldn't do it within your `IF` command to check for the file size.   If you wanted to do it within your if command then you literally give it the actual file name. `7z a -tzip archive.zip %%A`

Comment: No, I think I understand.
My `IF %%~zA LSS 1048576 (
        ECHO %%A >>.smaller.txt
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO %%A >>.larger.txt
    )` is creating the list of files.
So after that I would add my code `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a -mx9 -tzip "%ZIPNAME2%" "@.smaller.txt"` which would get the files from ".smaller.txt" and compress it. I was just wondering if that that was the best/most efficient way.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I believe creating the list file is the most efficient.  If you chose to keep adding a new file to the zip file, then a new process is constantly opening the zip file and adding to it.

Comment: feel free to post your final working code as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my end product.. 
Thanks for all the help!

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a IN ('date /t') DO (SET mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
FOR /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a IN ("%TIME%") DO (SET mytime=%%a%%b)
REM     My timestamp

SET FOLDER=%~dp1
REM     Sets current directory

IF NOT EXIST %SYSTEMDRIVE%\Logs MKDIR %SYSTEMDRIVE%\Logs
SET LOG="%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Logs\.picture_log.txt"
REM     Logging file and directory

PUSHD %FOLDER%
REM     Changes directory to current

FOR %%A IN ("%CD%") DO SET NAME=%%~NA
REM     Gets the last directory name and sets it as a variable

SET ZIP_O=%NAME% - Originals.zip
SET ZIP_R=%NAME% - Photos.zip
REM     Zip file names

IF EXIST ".larger.txt" DEL /F ".larger.txt"
IF EXIST ".smaller.txt" DEL /F ".smaller.txt"
REM     Delete old temporary files

IF EXIST "%ZIP_O%" DEL /F "%ZIP_O%" | ECHO %MYDATE%_%MYTIME%: %COMPUTERNAME% deleted %ZIP_O%>>%LOG%
IF EXIST "%ZIP_R%" DEL /F "%ZIP_R%" | ECHO %MYDATE%_%MYTIME%: %COMPUTERNAME% deleted %ZIP_R%>>%LOG%
REM     Deletes old zips if they exists

FOR /F "usebackq delims=;" %%A IN (`dir /b *.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.gif *.bmp`) DO (
    IF %%~zA LSS 1048576 (
        ECHO %%A >>.smaller.txt
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO %%A >>.larger.txt
    )
)
REM     Generate list of files, based off size

FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x IN (.larger.txt) DO SET LARGER=!LARGER!%%x
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x IN (.smaller.txt) DO SET SMALLER=!SMALLER!%%x
REM     Read lists, put contents into variables

"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a -mx9 -tzip "%ZIP_O%" @.larger.txt -sdel | ECHO %MYDATE%_%MYTIME%: %COMPUTERNAME% compressed %ZIP_O%>>%LOG%
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a -mx9 -tzip "%ZIP_R%" @.smaller.txt -sdel | ECHO %MYDATE%_%MYTIME%: %COMPUTERNAME% compressed %ZIP_R%>>%LOG%
REM     Compress images in separate .zips

IF EXIST ".larger.txt" DEL /F ".larger.txt"
IF EXIST ".smaller.txt" DEL /F ".smaller.txt"
REM     Delete temporary files
```

Answer (score 0):

The `forfiles` feature has a `@fsize` attribute, you can check.

For each file, which is large enough, you perform a `7z.exe a` (add to archive).

Comment: That does not help, I can get the file sizes already. My problem is getting 7zip to zip a list of files listed in my temporary text file (unless there is a better way than a temp file).